# How to properly handle library errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I need to use a library to access the API of a third-party resource..

```
from thirdparty import Client

client = Client(credentials)
```

And in our case, the credentials are incorrect, respectively, an error occurs inside the library due to the fact that the login request was unsuccessful. Application closes due to an error.

Let's say you can use Try-Except, but it does not look very effective

```
try:
    client = Client(credentials)
except:
   # do something with error
```

If we need to do a lot of different actions, then wrap each one in a Try-Except? Then you get something like:

```
try:
    friends= client.get_friends()
except:
   # do something with error

try:
    for friend in friends:
        info = client.send_message(friend, "My message")
except:
   # do something with error
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Yes, that's how you handle it. If the library chooses to raise an exception when there's an error, then you'll have to `except` that exception, otherwise your application will crash.

Comment: Put for loop inside 1st try block.

Comment: Additionally, a *specific* `Exception` class should be used to trap expected / then unexpected errors.  Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#concrete-exceptions) for detail.

Comment: No, you don't wrap single calls with `try`/`except` but rather a consecutive group or a function making multiple calls. What is "do something with error"? If it's just a log and terminate, then you can do that in `main()`. If it's to return a 500 error, do that in a middleware. Also, BTW, your application does not crash in an uncontrolled way. Rather, it terminates and emits a backtrace which can be used to diagnose the problem.